# For performance purposes, is "document" better off as one global variable or repeated hundreds of times locally?

Tags: javascript, performance, global-variables

I am not sure if Stack Overflow is the right forum for this particular question but here goes. I am trying to trim the fat out of my external js file. I came across this article:

[http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html[1](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html)

I scanned my js file and found 250 instances of **document** in various functions, e.g.,

```
function first() {
    document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'none';
    alert('Hi');
}

function second() {
    document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = 'foo bar';
    alert('Hello');
}
//etc
```

I can leave these 250 or so lines as is or trim about 1.7 kB out of my file by writing (note: no other variables in any function are named d):

```
var d = document;

function first() {
    d.getElementById('id1').style.display = x;
    alert('Hi');
}

function second() {
    d.getElementById('id2').innerHTML = y;
    alert('Hello');
}
//etc
```

I understand the article in the link, but for page speed wouldn't it be better to initialize **document** one time as a global (assuming no refreshes/reloads), keep it in memory, and then have it at the ready 250 times for the other functions?

Comment: I think you're asking whether, from a performance perspective, there's an advantage to aliasing `document` to a single-letter global variable if it's referred to frequently throughout the codebase? Interesting question. In terms of reducing the size of the file to serve to the user, the answer is obviously yes. Whether there is any performance disadvantage to this at execution-time, I don't know, but I would imagine that if there is it's tiny.

Comment: Actually the size difference doesn't matter as long as you serve gzipped files. repeated words like that would get heavily compressed.

Comment: I thought speedy websites heavily relied on the use of variables, files (especially images) etc. in memory...am I wrong about this?

Comment: Yes...all the files are gzipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with ALL performance questions, you really must measure in several browsers in order to draw accurate conclusions.

`document` itself is a global variable so we would think there would be little difference in run-time execution performance when referencing either global variable `d` or global variable `document`.

This conclusion is verified by this jsperf: http://jsperf.com/alias-document.

---

Within a scope, there are performance advantages to referencing local variables.  Local variables are accessed quicker than global variables (they are found earlier in the scope search) so if you are repeatedly accessing a global variable within the same scope, you can improve performance by pulling that global variable into a local variable within your function.  In general, I wouldn't bother with an alias unless this was an extremely performance-sensitive piece of code.

Comment: I checked out the link...thanks for the great answer.